# How do I set the initial offset in a PanGestureHandler from react-native-gesture-handler?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

In the following simple slider (typescript) example the PanGestureHandler from react-native-gesture-handler will only be set after the gesture was started. The user would need to move the finger.

This is what I would like to achieve: Taps should also set the slider value (including tap and drag). This is a common pattern, e.g. when seeking through a video file or setting volume to max and then adjusting.

I guess I could wrap this in a TapGestureHandler but I'm seeking the most elegant way to achieve this without too much boilerplate.

```js
// example extracted from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated-slider
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { PanGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const { Value, event, cond, eq, Extrapolate, interpolate } = Animated;

interface IProps {
  minimumTrackTintColor: string;
  maximumTrackTintColor: string;
  cacheTrackTintColor: string;
  value: number;
  style: any;
  cache;
  onSlidingStart;
  onSlidingComplete;
}
class Slider extends Component<IProps, {}> {
  static defaultProps = {
    minimumTrackTintColor: '#f3f',
    maximumTrackTintColor: 'transparent',
    cacheTrackTintColor: '#777',
  };

  private gestureState;
  private x;
  private width;
  private clamped_x;
  private onGestureEvent;

  public constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);

    this.gestureState = new Value(State.UNDETERMINED);
    this.x = new Value(0);
    this.width = new Value(0);

    this.clamped_x = cond(
      eq(this.width, 0),
      0,
      interpolate(this.x, {
        inputRange: [0, this.width],
        outputRange: [0, this.width],
        extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
      })
    );

    this.onGestureEvent = event([
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          state: this.gestureState,
          x: this.x,
        },
      },
    ]);
  }

  onLayout = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    this.width.setValue(nativeEvent.layout.width);
  };

  render() {
    const { style, minimumTrackTintColor, maximumTrackTintColor } = this.props;

    return (
      <PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={this.onGestureEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={this.onGestureEvent}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            {
              flex: 1,
              height: 30,
              overflow: 'visible',
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              backgroundColor: '#3330',
            },
            style,
          ]}
          onLayout={this.onLayout}
        >
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: 5,
              borderRadius: 2,
              overflow: 'hidden',
              borderWidth: 1,
              backgroundColor: maximumTrackTintColor,
            }}
          >
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: minimumTrackTintColor,
                height: '100%',
                maxWidth: '100%',
                width: this.clamped_x,
                position: 'absolute',
              }}
            />
          </Animated.View>
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider;
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: This works as intended, but has a visible render quirk and also a small delay.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { PanGestureHandler, TapGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const { Value, event, cond, eq, Extrapolate, interpolate } = Animated;

interface IProps {
  minimumTrackTintColor?: string;
  maximumTrackTintColor?: string;
  cacheTrackTintColor?: string;
  value: number;
  style?: any;
  onSlidingStart;
  onSlidingComplete;
}
class Slider extends Component<IProps, {}> {
  static defaultProps = {
    minimumTrackTintColor: '#f3f',
    maximumTrackTintColor: 'transparent',
    cacheTrackTintColor: '#777',
  };

  private gestureState;
  private x;
  private width;
  private clamped_x;
  private onGestureEvent;
  private onTapGesture;
  public constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);

    this.gestureState = new Value(State.UNDETERMINED);
    this.x = new Value(0);
    this.width = new Value(0);

    this.clamped_x = cond(
      eq(this.width, 0),
      0,
      interpolate(this.x, {
        inputRange: [0, this.width],
        outputRange: [0, this.width],
        extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
      })
    );

    this.onGestureEvent = event([
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          state: this.gestureState,
          x: this.x,
        },
      },
    ]);

    this.onTapGesture = event([
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          state: this.gestureState,
          x: this.x,
        },
      },
    ]);
  }

  onLayout = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    this.width.setValue(nativeEvent.layout.width);
  };

  render() {
    const { style, minimumTrackTintColor, maximumTrackTintColor } = this.props;

    return (
      <TapGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={this.onTapGesture}
        onHandlerStateChange={this.onTapGesture}
      >
        <Animated.View>
          <PanGestureHandler
            onGestureEvent={this.onGestureEvent}
            onHandlerStateChange={this.onGestureEvent}
          >
            <Animated.View
              style={[
                {
                  flex: 1,
                  height: 30,
                  overflow: 'visible',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  backgroundColor: '#3330',
                },
                style,
              ]}
              onLayout={this.onLayout}
            >
              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  width: '100%',
                  height: 5,
                  borderRadius: 2,
                  overflow: 'hidden',
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  backgroundColor: maximumTrackTintColor,
                }}
              >
                <Animated.View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: minimumTrackTintColor,
                    height: '100%',
                    maxWidth: '100%',
                    width: this.clamped_x,
                    position: 'absolute',
                  }}
                />
              </Animated.View>
            </Animated.View>
          </PanGestureHandler>
        </Animated.View>
      </TapGestureHandler>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider;
```

Comment: StackOverflow asked me to ask you to add my proposed tags: react-native-reanimated and react-native-gesture-handler. If you don't think they are necessary... well don't :)

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://github.com/alikazemkhanloo/react-native-reanimated-slider/blob/master/src/Slider.js)  to get some hints ?

Comment: Thanks @Cris69! I should have made it more prominent, but the first example states in the first line, that I extracted the example from there ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>After reading the documentation several times I figured it out. It's simpler than expected :)</strike>

```
<PanGestureHandler
   onGestureEvent={this.onGestureEvent}
   onHandlerStateChange={this.onGestureEvent}
   minDist={0}
>
```

The property `minDist` can be set to `0`.

Actually one needs to use the LongPressGestureHandler, as the PanHandler only changes it's state after some initial movement and not on touch begin.

The solution is to use something like:

```
<LongPressGestureHandler
    onGestureEvent={this.onGestureEvent}
    onHandlerStateChange={this.onGestureEvent}
    minDurationMs={0}
    maxDist={Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}
    shouldCancelWhenOutside={false}
    hitSlop={10}
>
{...}
</LongPressGestureHandler>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add some sort of checks in the onGestureFunciton? Or can we only use the event directly? See this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330969/stop-dragging-after-a-limit-has-reached